# Does the thread id change after forking a new process?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, fork

I know that this fork creates a new process, but what about the thread that was running prior to calling fork, does it also change (because now it is part of a new process "child process" which should have new threads ?)

Compiling and running the following C test confirms that the thread id remains the same:

```
  pthread_t threadId1, threadId2;

  threadId1 = pthread_self();
  if (fork() == 0)
  {
    threadId2 = pthread_self();
    if (pthread_equal(threadId1,threadId2)) // edited
    {
      printf("we are in the same thread \n");
    }
   else
    {
     printf("we are on different threads \n");
    }
```

Could someone explain to me why the thread is shared among the parent and child process ?

Comment: Thread ids are *opaque* data, you should not use direct comparison of them. Instead use [`pthread_equal`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_equal.3.html).

Comment: Use gettid() rather than the opaque pthread_t structure.

Comment: Yes, I just compare and print the result of the comparison of thread id before forking and in the child process.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe threads are tied up to a parent process and their ids are unique only within it. Therefore you can get the same ids.

Comment: Moreover POSIX standard claims that comparing threads with '==' is not appropriate way. You have to use pthread_equal.

Comment: Yes I have changed the code and used pthread_equal as @Someprogrammerdude have suggested.

Comment: Funny thing, if you are using glibc and compile with optimization, this code only does a single call to pthread_self (that function is marked with attribute `const`)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read [the `pthread_self` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_self.3.html) you will see that

> Thread IDs are guaranteed to be unique only **within a process**.

<sub>(Emphasis mine)</sub>

That of course means that two very different processes may have threads with the same id.

If you for some reason want to get the unique kernel id of the thread, use [`gettid`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettid.2.html) instead.

Comment: I have missed that Thank you.

Comment: Is there a 't' missing because the link is to gettid?

Comment: @SoulfreezerXP Yes that was a typo.

Answer (score 3):

From the man pages of pthread_self

```
   Thread IDs are guaranteed to be unique only within a process.  A
   thread ID may be reused after a terminated thread has been joined, or
   a detached thread has terminated.

   The thread ID returned by pthread_self() is not the same thing as the
   kernel thread ID returned by a call to gettid(2).
```

Since fork effectively duplicates a process, including its handles to kernel objects, the result therefore is not unexpected. (The kernel uses both handle value and pid when doing object lookup)